# Bind expression in linq without a variable assignment

Tags: c#, linq, monads

I wrote a little lazy IO type of monad in C# and tried using the linq syntax to make the code more readable.

Is there a way I can do a bind without a variable assignment for operations that are just called for their side effects?

The `Print(...)` in this example always returns `Void.Void`:

```
static IO<Void> Foo()
{
    var foo = from i in Return(2)
              from _1 in Print("Enter a number")
              from input in ReadInt()
              from _2 in Print("You entered: " + input)
              from j in Increment(input).Bind(Square)
              from sum in Add(j, input)
              from _3 in Print("i = " + i)
              from _4 in Print("j = " + j)
              from condition in GreaterThan(j, 10)
              from _5 in If(condition,
                  Print("j is greater than 10"),
                  Print("j is not greater than 10"))
              from _6 in Print("sum = " + sum)
              select Void.Void;
    return foo;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible.  You need to select out something.

Fundamentally the query syntax is designed for writing queries, not for monads in general, so the syntax is not designed to be particularly effective or elegant when used in this context.

Using query syntax for monads is a somewhat interesting intellectual exercise, but it's simply not very practical.